# What are the polarizations of an entangled photon pair?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-entanglement, polarization

My understanding of polarization of light is that a photon can be horizontally polarized, or vertically polarized, or some angle in between (eg 45 degrees from horizontal) — leaving aside circularly polarized for now.

This means basically that the electromagnetic wave oscillates in just this direction.

If you put a polarizing filter parallel to the direction of polarization, there is a 100% chance the photon goes through. If it’s perpendicular there is a 0% chance it goes through. If it’s somewhere in between there’s some other probability, eg for a 45 degree angle it’s 50% chance to go through.

My understanding with entangled photons is that it’s a pair of photons whose polarization is related to each other somehow. My question is - what is that “somehow”? Is the entangled pair polarized at 90 degrees to each other (such that if you sum their polarizations you get 0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that "it depends on the setup".

For example, in the entangled photon pair resulting from SPDC, where energy and momentum are conserved, the entangled photons have a "Type II polarization correlation" -- which means "their polarizations are perpendicular". ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion)).

Answer (score 0):

Electric fields and photons are a somewhat different descriptions of light. I'll stick to photons.

With photons, it's natural to pick the spin eigenstates ($j=1$, $j_z = \pm 1$), where  $z$ is the direction of propagation. Ofc $j_z=0$ is ruled out by gauge invariance.

So we call the two states $\pm$ helicity eigenstates with $|j,j_z\rangle$ as follows:

$$ |+\rangle = |1,+1\rangle $$
$$ |-\rangle = |1,-1\rangle $$

Any two state system is described by the Bloch Sphere, in the figure, the helicity eigenstates are at the poles (as complex combinations of the linearly polarized states $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$). Meanwhile, diagonal polarization are real mixtures of $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$ around the equator.

[image]

The general idea behind entangled photons is that they are produced from an initial state with known angular momentum quantum numbers $|j, m\rangle$.

What matters here is that the photons can be entangled in that state. Look at the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for two vector bosons:

[image]

The $j_1=j_2=1$ define the two final state photons spin. $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the z-projections of the spin. Note that $m_i=0$ is not allowed, so not all states of initial total $|j, m\rangle$ are possible.

What the table says is:

$$|++\rangle = |2, +2\rangle$$
$$|+-\rangle = \sqrt{\frac 1 6}|2, 0\rangle + \sqrt{\frac 1 2}|1, 0\rangle \sqrt{\frac 1 3}|0, 0\rangle$$
$$|-+\rangle = \sqrt{\frac 1 6}|2, 0\rangle - \sqrt{\frac 1 2}|1, 0\rangle \sqrt{\frac 1 3}|0, 0\rangle$$
$$|--\rangle = |2, -2\rangle$$

So a maximally polarized tensor particle ($|2,2\rangle$) decays to two parallel photons (Parity concerns notwithstanding):

$$|2,2\rangle\rightarrow |++\rangle $$

while

$$|1, 0\rangle -\rightarrow \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\big(|+-\rangle - |-+\rangle\big)$$

which is a more traditional entangled states since neither photon is in a helicity eigenstate. (I suspected they also in mixed $H$ and $V$ states...that just requires some 2x2 matrix math to verify).

Answer (score 0):

Entangled photons do not have individual states.  The **pair** has a state, which can't be expressed as a product of individual states.  This is what entanglement **means.**

Comment: Of course. My question is — so in the case of entangled 1/2 spin singlet, if one is measured of spin up at a given angle we know the other one will measure spin down at that same angle, because they are entangled. 

What about entangled photon pair? Is it if you measure one going through a X degree polarization filter, we know the other will always go through an X+90 degree polarization filter?

Comment: "in the case of entangled 1/2 spin singlet, if one is measured of spin up at a given angle we know the other one will measure spin down at that same angle, because they are entangled. "  Of course we know no such thing.  There are entangled states in which this is true and entangled states in which it is false.  Likewise for your question about the photons.

Comment: Indeed. Let me ask a more specific question then. In the entangled photon pair resulting from SPDC, where energy and momentum are conserved, and the entangled photons have a Type II polarization correlation — what precisely is the correlation of the polarizations, in this specific example?

Comment: Ah and I have found my answer , it’s that their polarizations are perpendicular.